# Launch Screen Not Working When Running On MeteorJS

Tags: ios, meteor

When using the command `meteor run ios-device --settings settings.json --mobile-server https://relyphe.com --production`

It opens the Xcode project with [2 errors](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8q39j28y08pguxb/Screenshot%202016-05-17%2016.33.39.png?dl=0). Which makes me unable to run the app.

```
App.icons({

  //iPhone Icons
  'iphone_2x': 'public/icon/iphone_2x.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'public/icon/iphone_3x.png',
  'ipad': 'public/icon/ipad.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'public/icon/ipad_2x.png',
  'ipad_pro': 'public/icon/ipad_pro.png',
  'ios_settings': 'public/icon/ios_settings.png',
  'ios_settings_2x': 'public/icon/ios_settings_3x.png',
  'ios_spotlight': 'public/icon/ios_spotlight.png',
  'ios_spotlight_2x': 'public/icon/ios_spotlight_2x.png',

  //Android Icons
  'android_mdpi': 'public/icon/android_mdpi.png',
  'android_hdpi': 'public/icon/android_hdpi.png',
  'android_xhdpi': 'public/icon/android_xhdpi.png',
  'android_xxhdpi': 'public/icon/android_xxhdpi.png',
  'android_xxxhdpi': 'public/icon/android_xxxhdpi.png'
});

App.launchScreens({

  // iPhone Launchscreens
  'iphone_2x': 'public/launch/iphone_2x.png',
  'iphone5': 'public/launch/iphone5.png',
  'iphone6': 'public/launch/iphone6.png',
  'iphone6p_portrait': 'public/launch/iphone6p_portrait.png',
  'iphone6p_landscape': 'public/launch/iphone6p_landscape.png',
  'ipad_portrait': 'public/launch/ipad_portrait.png',
  'ipad_portrait_2x': 'public/launch/ipad_portrait_2x.png',
  'ipad_landscape': 'public/launch/ipad_landscape.png',
  'ipad_landscape_2x': 'public/launch/ipad_landscape_2x.png',

  // Android Launchscreens
  'android_mdpi_portrait': 'public/launch/android_mdpi_portrait.png',
  'android_mdpi_landscape': 'public/launch/android_mdpi_landscape.png',
  'android_hdpi_portrait': 'public/launch/android_hdpi_portrait.png',
  'android_hdpi_landscape': 'public/launch/android_hdpi_landscape.png',
  'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'public/launch/android_xhdpi_portrait.png',
  'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'public/launch/android_xhdpi_landscape.png',
  'android_xxhdpi_portrait': 'public/launch/android_xxhdpi_portrait.png',
  'android_xxhdpi_landscape': 'public/launch/android_xxhdpi_landscape.png'
});
```

After that when running the app it shows the app with black bars at the top and bottom. [Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44x9ub5lzwnrfgr/Photo%20May%2016%2C%209%2033%2018%20PM.png?dl=0)

I followed the Meteor documentation and the sizes for the launch screens and the app icon. Put them in the mobile-config.js file and used the command stated above? Why is Xcode showing this error when I have followed the Meteor documentation exactly. Is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced issues specifying the public folder as well. Try without it (launch/android_mdpi_portrait.png)